# Select specific database in mongorc.js

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell, nosql

Is it possible to select a database that MongoDB should use on startup in the mongorc.js?

```
use dbname
```

is not functioning. This is a Non-JavaScript macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The db-name is an option when starting the mongo javascript shell.

> mongo
>
> mongo --help

You can also do something similar like this from the js file

> db = db.getSiblingDB("dbname")

Comment: I know for startup but the second one was important. Thanks